# Can I shorten a string of childNodes[0]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom

I have this line of code. It works just fine, but I'm wondering if there's a smarter (read: shorter) way of doing it?

```
      svg.getElementById($(this).attr('id')).childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = $(this).val();
```

I'm using jQuery as well, so any jQuery methods are fine :)

The markup being reached is

```
<text id=n>
<tspan>text to reach</tspan>
</text>
```

It would be ideal, however, if I could reach the text even if the  tags were removed.

Comment: Can you paste your markup, explaining which element you're trying to reach?

Comment: `Element.textContent` will net you the text from the perspective of the id element, but it doesn't work in IE < 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should let you change the text:

```
$("#" + $(this).attr("id") + " tspan").text($(this).val());
```

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't let me change the value. I couldn't say
`$("#" + $(this).attr("id") + " tspan").text() = $(this).val();`

Comment: @Eric, I didn't know you were trying to change it. I've updated my answer. `text()` works both as a getter and a setter depending on whether you pass an argument to it.

Comment: A word of caution : Won't this change all tspans in id (if there were more than one)?

Comment: Ah, it was part of my original code :) No worries. Works great!

Comment: @Hans it could, my Inkscape generated SVG files only use one though.

Any idea how we could make it dynamic so that it could change the text inside <text></text> tags whether or not there is also a <tspan></tspan> tag inside?

Comment: @eric I don't know query sufficiently well but something like ($("#" + $(this).attr("id") + " tspan") || $("#" + $(this).attr("id"))).text() might work.

Comment: @Hans Figured it out :) Posted below.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a kludge, but it'll substitute the end node value of a text element whether it has a tspan element or not. This example acts on an input field with a class of 'replace'.

```
$('.replace').keyup(function() {    
  if ($("#" + $(this).attr("id")).has("tspan").length) {
    $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + " tspan").text($(this).val());
  } else {
    $("#" + $(this).attr("id")).text($(this).val());
  }
}
```

Comment: My version : $('.replace').keyup(function() {    
  $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + ($("#" + $(this).attr("id")).has("tspan").length ? " tspan" : '')).text($(this).val());  Shorter, if slighlty less readable
}